# What is the suggested alternative for the deprecated Face3?

Tags: three.js, geometry, face, buffer-geometry

I know `THREE.Geometry` was deprecated in favor of `THREE.BufferGeometry()`. However, there doesn't seem to be any clear information about how to implement what was once "`Face3()`".  My understanding is that it was somehow related to the `Geometry()` object, but I'm not sure how because the documentation has been removed.

I'm trying to get some old example running that used `Face3()`.

Could someone provide a simple translation from `Face3()` to its suggested newer alternative please?

Here's an example to work with:

```
const points = []
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(-5, 0, 0))
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, 0))
points.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 5, 0))
let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points )
var face = new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2); //Error: Face3 is not a constructor
```

I've tried reading through [this thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401/13) but there doesn't seem to be any real information on `Face3()` here. Also, when I search the threejs.org documentaiton for "face", there are no relevant results.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Well, for the time being, if you are using modules, `Face3` has been added as an export to [examples/jsm/deprecated/Geometry.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/33497f2fad7afa87f2d052b8b2e84bbe347b5425#diff-869cf08b53b8aab08cc1ba7106e540986f6e78e80e93ae3be469980e94ac83f2), but this /deprecated/ directory has been deleted from the threejs repo so if you're using an up-to-date version of threejs you'll have to localize the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change from THREE.Geometry to THREE.BufferGeometry gives three.js a similar representation of the mesh to what WebGL requires, allowing better performance without additional processing overhead. Each 'face' is specified as the indices of three vertices in the vertex list — not as an explicit JavaScript object for each face, which is expensive. An example constructing a new geometry would be:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

// specify vertex positions
geometry.setAttribute( 'position', 
  new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( [
    -5, 0, 0, // vertex 1
    5, 0, 0,  // vertex 2 
    0, 5, 0   // vertex 3
  ], 3 ) )
);

// specify triangles, as triplets of indexes into the vertex list.
geometry.setIndex( new THREE.BufferAttribute( [ 0, 1, 2 ], 1 ) );
```

The index in the example above is optional. If omitted, each triplet of three vertices in the geometry will be considered a unique triangle. The index is needed when you want to share the same vertices among multiple triangles.

See [THREE.BufferGeometry documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=buffergeo#api/en/core/BufferGeometry) for more details.

In some situations it may be useful to construct a [THREE.Triangle](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=triangle#api/en/math/Triangle) to temporarily represent a particular face of the mesh. These are not part of the rendering process but may be useful for computations.

```js
const face = new THREE.Triangle()
  .setFromAttributeAndIndices( geometry.attributes.position, 0, 1, 2 );

const area = face.getArea();
```